# How do I append the columns and values of Dataframe2 based on the index value of Dataframe 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

df1

```
+----------------------+
|index|  2   |  3      |
+------------+---------+ 
|  0  |  Q   | list1   |
|  1  |  R   | list2   |
+------------+---------+
```

df2

```
+------------+
|index|  1   |
+--------+---- 
|  0  |  A   |
|  1  |  B   | 
|  2  |  B   |
|  3  |  C   |
+------------+
```

How do I make my pandas dataframe become

```
+-----+------+------+----------+
|index|  1   |  2   |    3     |
+--------+---|------+----------+
|  0  |  A   |  Q   |  list1   |
|  1  |  B   |  R   |  list2   |
|  2  |  B   |  Q   |  list1   |
|  3  |  C   |  R   |  list2   |
+------------+------+----------+
```

To make a long story short I have a very dynamic mongodb array that produces different similar results but the array can be of length 1 to length 50 depending on the scenario. I was able to unwind the array regex out the specific values and put it into df1. However the array is in a list of lists (df1[column: 3]).

I broke the list of lists up and got the values I want and put them all into a new dataframe df2. I need to now be able combine df1 and df2 together based on the row value of df1. And yes I need the duplicate values.

DF1 can have as many rows as possible, I want to merge based on the values in the lists which are in column 3 of DF1. DF2 is created from the the list in DF1 where I am creating it based on a certain string. That list can have more than one of the same string in that list.

This is how I created df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1]])


count = 0
countj = 0

for i in df1['3']:
   
   for j in i:
      if j[0] == 'A' or j[0] == 'B' or j[0] == 'C':
         newdf.loc[countj] = j
      countj+=1
   
   count+=1
```

Comment: It's not clear how `df1` and `df2` are supposed to join to each other. Can you please [edit] your question with more explanation, including what happens if `df1` has more or less than 2 rows.

Comment: Hi I modified it I hope that helps

Comment: You need to use [df.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), something like this: `df2.merge(df1, how=‘left’, left_on=1, right_on=2)`

Comment: If the values in `df2` came from the lists in `df1`, then why are you merging `B` with *both* `list1` and `list2`? Is `B` in both of those lists? Your inputs and expected output don't make any sense.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me, can you make a clearer example?

Comment: You need to give an example of the values in list1 and list2 which give the result you show.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

I am not sure what you are asking for exactly.

If you want to arrange the values of df2 in a sequential order in df1, use the following code.

```
out = df2.merge(df1, how='left', left_on=df2['index'].mod(len(df1)), 
                right_on='index', suffixes=['', '_y']).drop('index_y', axis=1)
```

out:

[image]

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'index': [0, 1], '2': ['Q', 'R'], '3': ['list1', 'list2']}
data2 = {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3], '1': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

[image]